# Magento 2 how to get get product ID in after plugin?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, after-plugin

please help, I'm struggling with this.

I'm using this plugin

```
public function afterAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
```

I'm trying to get the product Id of the product in this way:

```
$productId = $subject->getId();

$productId = $productInfot->getId();
```

none of this works, i'm getting nothing, when I print with echo I get this:

```
Product ID:
```

I'm struggling a lot with this, I could get the product ID with beforeAddProduct in this way, but I must use afterAddProduct because is the only plugin that fits my solution.

Greetings!

Comment: Hi, I need to check your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `afterAddProduct()`, you can get the product Id with `$requestInfo` param. Below is the example code for getting product Id in `afterAddProduct()`.

```
public function afterAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{
    $productId = $requestInfo->getEntityId();
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly!